# ¿Cómo agregar texto en los espacios en blanco con ironpdf?

Tags: c#

mi pregunta es si ironpdf tiene la funcionalidad de agregar texto en los espacios en blanco de un archivo html antes de convertirlo a pdf. Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Te fijaste en la documentacion?

Comment: Ya revise la documentación y no encuentre nada, por eso me vi obligado a preguntar por este medio y el soporte de ironpdf no contesta